# Adding 3rd party framework into gyp config files

Tags: macos, chromium, gyp

I'm experimenting with compiling Chromium on Mac OS and want to add a 3rd party framework to the project.

I already added my TParty.framework to the chrome_browser.gypi as following:

```
...
   ['OS=="mac"', {
      'dependencies': [
        '../third_party/google_toolbox_for_mac/google_toolbox_for_mac.gyp:google_toolbox_for_mac',
        ...
      ],
      'link_settings': {
        'libraries': [
          '../third_party/TParty.framework',
          '$(SDKROOT)/System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework',
          '$(SDKROOT)/System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBook.framework',
          ...
        ],
      },
    }],
...
```

Then somewhere in the code I import header from this framework:

```
#import <TParty/main_header.h>
```

I believe this is the correct approach but compiler gives me an error:

fatal error: 'TParty/main_header.h' file not found

How can I fix the configs so that TParty.framework became available to the compiler?

There will be no error if I'd import the header directly, like this:

```
#import "../third_party/TParty.framework/Versions/A/Headers/main_header.h"
```

But importing this way looks to be a bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set a path to the framework with `mac_framework_dirs` GYP directive:

```
...
   ['OS=="mac"', {
      'dependencies': [
        '../third_party/google_toolbox_for_mac/google_toolbox_for_mac.gyp:google_toolbox_for_mac',
        ...
      ],
      'link_settings': {
        'libraries': [
          'TParty.framework',
          'Accelerate.framework',
          'AddressBook.framework',
          ...
        ],
        'mac_framework_dirs': [
          '../third_party',
          '$(SDKROOT)/System/Library/Frameworks', # probably the system path is used by default
        ],
      },
    }],
...
```

Comment: Thanks pmed. 
Indeed, mac_framework_dirs section does the job - my 3rd party framework is recognised by compiler.

However, built app has error on start: "crashes on start with error: dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/TParty.framework/Versions/A/TParty". Will handle it by myself.